# why jquery plugin function is always returning object instead of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

here is my code for a custom jquery plugin :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        getmyValue : function(){
        return this.each(function() {
                return this.myVal;
        });
        },
        initPlugin : function(){
        return this.each(function() {
                this.myVal='Some results';
        });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

when i run this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#div").initPlugin();
alert($("#div").getmyValue());
});
```

the returned value is not a plain string as supposed but an object ( $("#div") is returned )

what i can't figure out is why the return chaining is not working ?

Comment: You're returning the result of `this.each`, which is not a string. Why don't you just return `this.myVal`? It's unclear what you're trying  to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the return value of `each` is the object on which you called `each`. The return value of the function `each` *calls* is used to determine whether to stop looping (that is, the iteration function can return `false` to stop looping — [docs link](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

It's unclear from your code what you really want to do in `getmyValue`; return a value you've stored on the jQuery instance itself? Return the `myVal` stored on the first contained element? Return an array of the `myVal` values from all the contained elements?

If you meant a `myVal` stored on the jQuery instance by your plugin:

```
getmyValue : function(){
    // Here, `this` is the jQuery instance on which `getmyvalue` was called
    return this.myVal;
},
```

If you meant the `myVal` on the first element (note that it's a raw DOM element in the typical case):

```
getmyValue : function(){
    // Here, `this` is the jQuery instance on which `getmyvalue` was called.
    // `this[0]` is the first matched element (a raw DOM element, typically).
    // Note we check before accessing it to see if it's there, since a jQuery
    // instance may have matched zero elements.
    return this[0] ? this[0].myVal : undefined;
},
```

If you meant an array of the `myVal` values from all the matched elements (again, these will be raw DOM elements in the typical case):

```
getmyValue : function(){
    // Here, `this` is the jQuery instance on which `getmyvalue` was called.
    return this.map(function() {
            // Here, though, `this` one of the elements wrapped by the jQuery,
            // instance typically a raw DOM element. (Each of them in a loop.)
            return this.myVal;
    }).get();
},
```

...which uses [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get a jQuery-wrapped array of the values, and then [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the raw array from it.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the result of `this.each()` rather than `this.myVal`:

```
getmyValue: function() {
    return this.myVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of the `.each` is an object. If you replace that with `.map` then your code will return a comma delimited list of values.

[jQuery Map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: *"If you replace that with .map then your code will return a comma delimited list of values."* No, it will return a jQuery instance wrapping the values. Per the very docs you linked.

Comment: I was missing the `.get().join(',');`. This will take the return values and format them properly.